# Delete user data programmatically in android

Tags: android, admin

I'm looking for a way to delete user data programmatically in android, I don't know if android allows that. 
Thanks

Comment: And by "user data", you mean exactly what?

Comment: logout user from apps like skype,facebook,evernote....Delete his gmail account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, this is not possible, for obvious reasons.

If you are configured by the user to be [a device administrator](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html), [you can use `wipeData()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#wipeData%28int%29) to basically factory-reset the device.

Comment: if im a device administrator , can i use that privileges to clear data of a specific application on the device?

Comment: @ViVekH: Not that I know of, but I do not have all of the device admin APIs memorized, sorry.

Comment: Sorry for the bother, im trying to clear data of other applications.
As per what i read up on device admin priveleges , i can wipe the entire user data i.e. factory reset , so stuck there.

Anyways thanks for your replies, your answers and replies have helped a lot over the years, cheers!